# Passing multiple models from View to Controller in asp MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

*Update*
here is my solution that worked for me:
I create two sub views one for Model1 and one for Model2
and in the big view model I render them by :

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("view1", Model.model1);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("view2", Model.model2);}
```

and in the controller I have Action method like this

```
BigViewModel model= new BigViewModel();
  return View(model);
```

and I have Action method for posting like this :

```
  [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult fun(Model1 model1,Model2 model2)
{
//Logic go here
}
```

=================================

I have a 2 models like this :

```
public class Model1 {
    ... more properties here ...
}

public class Model2 {
    ... more properties here ...
}
```

and then I created one big model : `

```
    public class BigViewModel {
    public Model1 model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 model2{ get; set; }
}
```

then created a strong typed view of type (BigViewModel)
so that user can edit the fields in that view and press submit button to back to server to process
`public ActionResult test(BigViewModel model)`

but the model is null.
I need a way to pass the BigViewModel to the controller.`

Comment: How do you instantiate the view model before passing it to the view? Show the controller code

Comment: You need to create an instance of BigViewModel when calling the view.

Comment: For this to work, your model being passed from your controller to the view needs to be the exact same one that you accept in your Action

Comment: I created an instance ` BigViewModel model = new BigViewModel ` and passed it to the view ` return View ( model ) `

Comment: *Note* I tried to make a view of type Model1 and also another view of type Model2 and in the big view I called @{Html.RenderPartial("Viewnamel", Model.model1);}

Comment: use ajax pass variables fill them within your controller?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I have models like this

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

}

public class BigViewModel
{
    public Model1 model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 model2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have httppost action method like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(BigViewModel vm)
    {
        if (vm == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I have razor view like this

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.BigViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>BigViewModel</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        @Html.EditorFor(s => s.model1.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(s => s.model2.Id)
    </div>


    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}

   <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

It works on my side