# Submitting Fom Returns 400 Status

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

In the view, I'm creating a Project. In the form I'm filling the project data. The project has services and for them I'm using the jQuery modal form for the CRUD operations on the Services. For CRUD operations I'm using AJAX. In this view I have 2 partial views - on for the form where I'm entering the service data and another partial view for updating the service data. The CRUD operations are working and I'm able to create, update or delete a service. I can do that without creating the project. However when I click the Submit button to create the project, it looks like the right method is no being called and I'm not able to create a project, I'm just getting white screen. The URL is the same as the one of URL where I'm filling the project form localhost:/Project/Create. I have tried deleting the jQuery where I'm adding a service with AJAX and then it looks like the data is submitted to the right method in the project controller. What is the reason for this - why I'm not able to process the form data when the jQuery code is there?

I have tried changing the AJAX call (it's always working and I'm able to create a service) as well as BigViewModel (as suggested here - [Passing multiple models from View to Controller in asp MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661138/passing-multiple-models-from-view-to-controller-in-asp-mvc-5)), but this is still not working...

Here is the method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(ProjectViewModel model)
{

    int audianceId = model.ProjectModel.AudienceId;
    int categoryId = model.ProjectModel.CategoryId;
    //...............................................
    //CREATE THE PROJECT AND ADD TO DATABASE
 }
```

Here is the AJAX call (from the View) when creating a service:

```
<script>
    var name = $("#ServiceModel_Name").val();
    var price = $("#ServiceModel_Price").val();
    var discount = $("#ServiceModel_Discount").val();
    var quantity = $("#ServiceModel_Quantity").val();
    var description = $("#ServiceModel_Description").val();
    var ir = $("#ServiceModel_IR").val();

    var details = { "name": name, "quantity": quantity, "price": price, "discount": discount, "description": description, "ir": ir };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Project/RegisterService",
        data: details,
        datatype: "json",
        async: "true",
        success: function (response) {
            var serviceId = response;                
            $("#confirmationMessage").text("Service successfully created!");
            $(function () {
                $("#dialogMessage").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        title: "Success!",
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    //BindData(response);
                                    //ClearForm();
                                    $("#service1").dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        }
    });
</script>
```

And the ProjectViewModel definition:

```
 public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        public CreateProjectViewModel ProjectModel { get; set; }

        public CreateServiceViewModel ServiceModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on your post action,you need to send RequestVerificationToken from headers if you need yo add antiforgery validation.

1.Add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form code.

2.Add header in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Project/RegisterService",
    data: details,
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    }, 
    async: "true",
    success: function (response) {

    }       
});
```

`dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc. jQuery will use this to figure out how to populate the success function's parameter.

Besides, make sure your ajax data corresponds to action parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult RegisterService(Project model)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The jQuery code I'm using is working just fine and I'm able to create Service, however, I'm not able to create a Project, which the form I'm trying to submit should do. So in the Project form, I have another form that is creating the Service. When I remove the jQuery code that is creating the service - I'm able to submit the Project data, but when I add back the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

how about trying

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] ProjectViewModel model)
{

    int audianceId = model.ProjectModel.AudienceId;
    int categoryId = model.ProjectModel.CategoryId;
    //...............................................
    //CREATE THE PROJECT AND ADD TO DATABASE
    return CreatedAtAction("Create", model);
 }


<script>
    var name = $("#ServiceModel_Name").val();
    var price = $("#ServiceModel_Price").val();
    var discount = $("#ServiceModel_Discount").val();
    var quantity = $("#ServiceModel_Quantity").val();
    var description = $("#ServiceModel_Description").val();
    var ir = $("#ServiceModel_IR").val();

    var details = { "name": name, "quantity": quantity, "price": price, "discount": discount, "description": description, "ir": ir };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Project/RegisterService",
        data: JSON.stringify(details),
        datatype: "json",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: "true",
        success: function (response) {
            var serviceId = response;                
            $("#confirmationMessage").text("Service successfully created!");
            $(function () {
                $("#dialogMessage").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        title: "Success!",
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    //BindData(response);
                                    //ClearForm();
                                    $("#service1").dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work as well. However I've tried removing [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and then everything is working fine..

Comment: if this did not work but xings solution did you may want to remove the correct check from this answer and put it on xings.